# Self restart self contained single file dotnet core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, application-restart, self-contained

Does anyone know a way or if it's possible to have a self contained single file dotnet core 3.1 console application to self restart? I've done this before in other console applications using the code below and it's worked, however it doesn't work for my single file application.

I instead get the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because the parent does not exist.
```

I suspect this is due to the runtime being contained in the directory and window's not knowing to use it. If I publish the application as a non single file application the restart works just fine using the exe. However I would prefer to use the self contained single file as it makes it much easier for people to transfer a single exe around.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
            UserName = creds.UserName,
            PasswordInClearText = creds.Password,
            Domain = "mydomain",
            Verb = "runas"
        };

        // Start the process
        Process.Start(info);

        // Exit the current one
        Environment.Exit(0);
```

I have looked at the Application.Restart method, however I need to use the runas verb as my application is dealing with kerberos tokens and has to run in the context of the user and pass that it prompted the user for.

Any help on this would be appreciated, I've been spinning my tires on this for about a day now. I've found many articles on how to create a single file app but not how to get one to restart it self.

Comment: Set `WorkingDirectory`? Not sure if this will solve it, but maybe :)

Comment: @John unfortunately setting the working directory didn't help.